# Submit wont work after zend, ajax / jquery validation

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery, jquery-validate

The follow problem I have,  I made for a form a ajax/jquery validation. The validation works fine after the submit, when something is wrong during the validation, I get the errorMessage. But, the problem is. When something is 'OK' it wont submit the input.

My js code;

```
    ValidateAjax = {

    initialize: function(formid, endpoint){
        end_url = endpoint;
        form_id = '#'+formid;

        $('form').submit(function(){
            var formElementID = $(form_id+' input').attr('id');
            $('.loader').hide();
            var check = ValidateAjax.doValidate(formElementID);
            return false;
        })
    },

    doValidate: function(id){
        $('.loader').show();
        var url = end_url;
        var data = $(form_id).serialize();
        $.post(url,data,function(response){
            $('#'+id).parent().find('.errors').remove();
            if (response[id])
                $('#'+id).parent().append(ValidateAjax.getHTML(response[id]));
        },'json');
    },

    getHTML: function(errArray){
        $('.loader').hide();
        var o = '<ul class="errors">';
        $.each(errArray,function(key,value){
            o+='<li>'+ value+'</li>';
        });
        o+='</ul>';
        return o;
    }
```

}

My index view;

```
<? echo $this->form; ?>
```

My validation action;

```
public function validateformAction()
{
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $form = new Application_Form_Add();
        $form->isValidPartial($_POST);
        $this->_helper->json($form->getMessages());
}
```

My index action;

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $form                 = new Application_Form_Add();
    $this->view->form     = $form;

    // submit new blog - Validated by ajax
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $data = $form->getValues();
            //do something
            $this->_redirect('/wall/');
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

With kind regards,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You are always returning 'false' from the submit call.
You need to return 'true' if there are no validation errors.